# NodeJS stdout python multiple prints?

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python script that prints JSON and string:

```
# script.py
print('{"name": "bob", "height": 4, "weight": 145}')
print('hello')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

A nodejs app calls the python script via `child-process`. But I'm getting error on the output. How can I process the python output in nodejs?

```
// nodejs
var process = spawn('python3', ["./script.py", toSend]);
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      message = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(message)
})
```

I'm getting this a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` from running this.

Comment: whats the error? You should add it to your post.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: in your python file.. you probably to use json.dumps() it sounds like the input that Node is expecting is not proper JSON... so JSON.parse is failing... try console.log(data) so that you can see what's wrong with the expected JSON.. also print('hello') will cause json.Parse() to fail since you are reading from stdout.. `Hello` is going to be parsed as JSON and its not JSON

Answer (score 2):

In your python script...
This line

```
print('{"name": "bob", "height": 4, "weight": 145}')
```

should be changed

```
import json
print(json.dumps({"name": "bob", "height": 4, "weight": 145}))
```

That will handle and make sure the JSON is formatted correctly, so that the JSON string can be parsed by node (but your current version should be fine). However in this case the real problem is what follows...

You are ending your script with

```
print('hello')
```

which means that JSON.parse() is going to try and parse `hello` as part of the JSON.parse() because you are reading from stdout... `hello` is not JSON formatted.  So JSON.parse() is going to fail. So remove that line as well.

If you have more then one json object to send as you stated in your comments

You can either combine all the data into a single JSON object 
`my_object = {"data": "info"....}` and `json.dumps()` that single larger object..

or

```
obj1 = {}
obj2 = {}
myobjects = [obj1, obj2]
print(json.dumps(myobjects))
```

and the Node side will recieve a list of objects that can be iterated on

Comment: If the python script prints 2 lines of JSON, does console.log output them as 1 chunk? How can I loop for each print from python?

Comment: You have to combine the JSON on the python side and send a single JSON object and read that single object on Node side. Or you can send a JSON array [{}, {}]